# Cited Authors with Biblabels in Index

Tags: bibtex, indexing

I want to include all cited authors in the index, but with the biblabel and not with the pagenumber. I tried `authorindex`, but I want one index not two different. I also tried `authorindex -i` but makeindex doesn't like the option `biblabels` because the labels are not correct page numbers.

How do I get a single index (with `\index{...}` entries and the cited authors) including the cited authors with the corresponding bibtex labels?

---

Here is a MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Cameron1994,
 AUTHOR = {Cameron, Peter Jephson},
 TITLE = {{Combinatorics}: {Topics}, {Techniques}, {Algorithms}},
 PUBLISHER = {Cambridge University Press},
 YEAR = {1994}
}
@ARTICLE{Cameron2008,
 AUTHOR = {Cameron, Peter Jephson and Gewurz, Daniele A. and Merola, Francesca},
 TITLE = {{Product} action},
 JOURNAL = {Discrete Math.},
 YEAR = {2008}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[biblabels]{authorindex}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
I \index{cite}cite something like \aicite{Cameron1994} and \aicite{Cameron2008}.
I want a \index{merged}merged index.

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\printindex
\printauthorindex
\end{document}
```

I compile with

```
pdflatex
bibtex
makeindex
authorindex
pdflatex
authorindex
pdflatex
```

I get two indices (one for `\printindex` and one for `\printauthorindex`):
[image: references]

[image: normal index]

[image: authorindex]

but what I want is a merged index like
[image: merged index]

To produce the last index I manipulated the `*.ind` file by hand.

---

I tried a solution by myself, but I failed: I used `authorindex -i -p MWE >> MWE.idx` to add the entries of the author index into the normal index. But I can not compile it with `makeindex`, because the "CGM08" (etc.) are not correct page numbers.

Comment: not sure to understand. You want something like `\index{author1~\cite{author1}}`?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution is more or less a hack. However it seems to work:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Cameron1994,
 AUTHOR = {Cameron, Peter Jephson},
 TITLE = {{Combinatorics}: {Topics}, {Techniques}, {Algorithms}},
 PUBLISHER = {Cambridge University Press},
 YEAR = {1994}
}
@ARTICLE{Cameron2008,
 AUTHOR = {Cameron, Peter Jephson and Gewurz, Daniele A. and Merola, Francesca},
 TITLE = {{Product} action},
 JOURNAL = {Discrete Math.},
 YEAR = {2008}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[biblabels]{authorindex}

\makeatletter
\def\gobble#1{}
\renewenvironment{theauthorindex}{%
\begingroup
  \let\indexspace\relax
  \def\item[##1]{\null\gdef\ItemIndex{##1}}
  \def\aipages##1{\index{\ItemIndex @{\ItemIndex~[##1]}\protect\gobble |gobble}}
}{\endgroup}
\makeatother

\makeindex
\begin{document}
I \index{cite}cite something like \aicite{Cameron1994} and \aicite{Cameron2008}.
I want a \index{merged}merged index.

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\printindex
\printauthorindex
\end{document}
```

After running the following compilation marathon twice:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: true }
% arara: bibtex
% arara: authorindex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: true }
% arara: authorindex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: true }
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: true }
```

I get the following output:

[image]

Comment: I have a little problem with this solution. In the index I get, all biblabels are empty. For example there is only "Merola, Francesca []", the "CGM08" inside the "[]" is missing. The IDX before the `makeindex` looks like `\indexentry{Merola, Francesca@{Merola, Francesca\nobreakspace  {}[]}\gobble |gobble}{1}`

Comment: @Ivo: That's the reason I wrote `marathon` I had to do the shown compilation steps twice.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks, I should read carefully. But why is there a separation between "Cameron ..." and "cite"?

Comment: @Ivo: Good question. I don't know ;-)

Comment: @Daniel: I changed `\protect\gobble` to `\protect\ignorespaces\protect\gobble`. Know it works for me.

Comment: @Ivo: Ah ok. Then everything is fine ;-)