# Where can I find a copy of the arara rule file 'authorindex.yaml' for 'authorindex'?

Tags: arara, authorindex

I am new to LaTeX. When I try to typeset my TeX file using Arara to run the 'authorindex' package, e.g. (*):

```
% arara: authorindex
```

I get the following message:

```
"I could not find a rule named 'authorindex' in the provided rule
paths. Perhaps a misspelled word? I was looking for a file named
'authorindex.yaml' in the following paths in order of priority:
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/rules)"
```

I checked the folder:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/scripts/arara/rules
```

but I did not see a copy of the `authorindex.yaml` rule file there (nor anywhere else within the 2020 texlive folders).

I've been unsuccessful at creating a custom `authorindex.yaml` file. I've searched SE, CTAN, etc. and the rest of the internet for a copy of a `authorindex.yaml` arara rule file, to no avail.

Any help locating or creating a `authorindex.yaml` rule file would be greatly appreciated.

(*) For reference, the `% arara: authorindex` command is mentioned in the answer below, "After running the following compilation marathon twice:" at:

[Cited Authors with Biblabels in Index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122289/cited-authors-with-biblabels-in-index/122412?newreg=204bdff46d1c4ae4ae119f63aff86c45)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is not a core rule (the ones in the official distribution are at https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/arara/-/tree/master/rules). Hence, you cannot locate the rule. Marco Daniel, who wrote the answer you linked to, is an arara contributor so he probably wrote his own rule for authorindex. Maybe Paulo Cereda will see your question and come up with a rule.

Comment: Thank you for the link, comment and for editing my post. Arara is an amazing package for what it is able to do. I wondered how Marco Daniel was able to execute the authorindex package using arara without seeing the same error; makes sense he 'rolled his own' arara rule file for authorindex. Is there an unofficial distribution of arara rules for such packages as 'authorindex'? Alternatively, is there an alternative to the 'authorindex' package that works with arara? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

arara version 5.1.3 (already on CTAN) contains a rule for `authorindex`. Have a look into the manual to see the options.

Comment: Thank you and stay safe ...